# formatting the user name

Tags: java, string-formatting

I had my username as domain\username, so if I do this

```
String username = "mydomain\myusername";
```

It gives an error, Can anyone let me know how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). One bullet point: _If your code doesn't compile, have you included the **exact** compiler error?_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\` is a meta character, it has special meaning. If you want yo use the meta characters as is, you need to escape it with `\`. Since you have `\` in `mydomain\myusername` you have to escape it with `\`

use

```
String username = "mydomain\\myusername";
```

Answer (score 4):

Backslashes are special characters used for escaping. e.g. \t is a tab, \n is a newline.
You have \m, which is not a valid escape sequence.

To actually have a backslash, it needs to be escaped:

```
String username = "mydomain\\myusername";
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the character `\`

so use `String username = "mydomain\\myusername";` instead